# Setting a primary key that generated identically and automatically in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I created an entity called `Student`

```
public class Student
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

When `Required` attribute is added to `Id` property, I have to input a value for `Id`. I want to generate `Id` property automatically and identity via EF Core.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      var db = new AppDbContext();
      db.Add(new Student { Name = "Peter" });
      db.SaveChanges();
  }
```

If I add `DatabaseGenerated` attribute, Does `Id` become the primary key?

How can I define a primary key that automatically generated and I do not have to set the key value for it?

Comment: Here is the documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#primary-keys. Basically you don't need to do anything, `int` type property called `Id` is automatically considered as auto generated PK by EF Core. Just don't add `[Required]` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the primary key using the `[Key]` attribute. It can be defined with your identity as:

```
public class Student
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: They can, but it's not needed. Their problem seems to be misunderstanding of the `Required` attribute they are applying to their property (and they shouldn't).

Comment: @IvanStoev So `Key` does not required to be defined by user?

Comment: @user7826774 The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations) is clear: "By convention, a property named `Id` or `<type name>Id` will be configured as the primary key of an entity.". And the other link I gave you starts with "By convention, non-composite primary keys of type short, int, long, or Guid are set up to have values generated for inserted entities if a value isn't provided by the application.". As you can see, in your case you don't need any attribute. As I mentioned twice, your problem is with adding `Required` attribute.